# Find next tag using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

So basically I using selenium for the following webpage: http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/schedule/catalog.aspx?sa=APPLING&funsel=3. I created a driver and I am looking for a bold text that matches some specific criteria. Below is part of my code that searches for the bold text and finds a matching:

```
# Finds all bold matches which contain the class title 
    bold_matches = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('bold')
    class_title = ''
    class_description = ''
    for bold_match in bold_matches:
        # If the class title matches, we set our class title
        if bold_match.text[:bold_match.text.find('.')] == class_number:
            class_title = bold_match.text
```

You don't need to worry about the code too much besides the fact that once we find an element that has a matching text, we set the text to the class title.

What I need help doing using Selenium is to get next tag of the matching text. So I need the tag right after the matching `bold_match`. The next tag contains text that would set the `class_description` text.

I have looked around similar questions, but they all refer to matching ids with xpath. The problem with this webpage is that the bold text tags and the tags after it do not contain any ids.

Comment: Is the tag you require a child or sibling of the 'bold_match' element? I'm sorry I couldn't quite grasp from your description.

Comment: I require the sibling of the bold_match element. I actually found out a hackish way to do it and I will post it as my answer. If you know a better way to do it, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hackish way to do what I need. Below is my code:

```
# Finds all bold matches which contain the class title 
bold_matches = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('bold')
class_title = ''
class_description = ''
for bold_match in bold_matches:
    # If the class title matches, we set our class title
    if bold_match.text[:bold_match.text.find('.')] == class_number:
        class_title = bold_match.text

        # We find the class description from the class title
        all_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*')
        matching_index = all_elements.index(bold_match) + 2
        class_description = all_elements[matching_index].text
```

What I found out is that I can just find the index of the element that I currently matched in the `a ll_elements` list and then find the next corresponding index to get the `class_description`.

Comment: That will work certianly but did you consider using the 'following-sibling' axes?
`bold_match.find_element_by_xpath("./following-sibling::tag_of_the_element_you_need")`

Comment: @MarkRowlands Thanks for the answer. I didn't know that we can use the `find_element_by_xpath()` method on any webdriver element.